# Vectorized way to obtain gradient of images in a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

If I have a matrix `A` that is a 3D matrix where each slice is an image, would it possible to use vectorised method to obtain the gradient for each slice without a loop? My current method:

```
A=rand(50,50,50);
grad=zeros(size(A));

for i=1:size(A,3)
    grad(:,:,i)=imgradient(A(:,:,i));
end
```

Current method will be very slow in performance as I'm dealing with huge amount of images in a 3D matrix. Wonder if there's a faster and cleaner way to obtain the gradient, something like simply `grad=imgradient(A)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the gradient magnitude of the images. You could use `gradient`, which accepts 3D matrices to obtain the vector components of the gradient `Gradx` and `Grady` and then calculate the magnitude:

```
[Gradx,Grady] = gradient(A)
Grad = sqrt(Gradx.^2 + Grady.^2)
```